# Getting Guild ID (randomly?) erroring sometimes after putting it into class

Tags: python, class, discord.py

I keep getting either  "Guild is not defined" errors, or "ctx does not have event guild", errors. Ever sense I switched my event to a listener when putting it into a class it seems to error. For some reason, maybe I'm not understanding how to pass params through classes and this is causing the error? I'm not really sure what is happening though.

my code:

```
#the class it's in 

class events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

[ . . . ]

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, ctx):

[ . .  . ]

#This is giving me the issue        

        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
```

It works sometimes, and then other times I just falls on it's face for 12 hours, I don't know why, but now I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you show your full error please?

Comment: I would, if it just didn't randomly start working after I restarted the bot again :)

Comment: `ctx has no event guild` 

is the usual error I get when running this overnight. Not sure why

Comment: If the message is sent in DMs you're gonna get an error, something like `NoneType has no attribute 'id'`, because `ctx.guild` (you should name it `message` instead) is `None`

Comment: ohhh here I thought I was doing classes all wrong, I understand now, thanks. Sorry for the late response, I just got home form work.